# Deformations for complex space germs

Tags: deformation-theory

Is there a space such that it doesn't have any deformation but its space of first order infinitesimal deformations is non trivial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such germs of spaces exist. See Section 7.6 of Ravi Vakil's paper *[Murphy's law in Algebraic Geometry](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411469)*.